# A C# gmail MailSender

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I have created an email sending function but it keeps getting timed out.

```
try
        {
            send.Enabled = false;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(senderemail.Text);
            message.Subject = subject.Text;
            message.Body = body.Text;
            foreach (string str in recipients.Text.Split(';'))
            {
                message.To.Add(str);
            }
            try
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderemail.Text, senderpassword.Text);
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.Port = 587;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Sent Successfully", "Details");
            }
            catch
            {
                SmtpClient client2 = new SmtpClient();
                client2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderemail.Text, senderpassword.Text);
                client2.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client2.Port = 465;
                client2.EnableSsl = true;
                client2.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Sent Successfully", "Details");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            send.Enabled = true;
        }
```

After a port analysis using telnet, I am clueless as to why the code won't execute properly.

Comment: where do you gen the error?

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/sc7sk0eyqpc520n9hhgg0kjncu8dw03h 

try this link for the uploaded version

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Comment: Nope it still shows an error at the line >> client.Send(message);

What was the intended outcome after the use of >> client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; ??

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/sc7sk0eyqpc520n9hhgg0kjncu8dw03h

try this link for the uploaded version